# How to remove Loopback model and references from database

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I removed a model fully from my app: deleted the `model.js` and `model.json` from `models`, deleted a relation in another model, and erased it from `model-config.json`.

However, the table created for the model, and the column in the other model remain in the DB (in all environments). I tried auto-migrating, but they're still there.

Do I need to manually go through all databases and drop the table and column manually, or can I tell LB to pick up the changes on its own somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it manually - in 3 databases :(

I'm closing the question, but willing to reopen if someone had a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to manually go through all databases and drop the table and column manually, or can I tell LB to pick up the changes on its own somehow?

LoopBack is not able to detect which models were removed and drop the corresponding database tables.

As you have discovered yourself, the solution is to go through the databases and drop the tables manually.

BTW I don't recommend using LoopBack's autoupdate/automigrate functionality in production and highly advocate for maintaining a set of migration scripts as described e.g. in Martin Fowler's excellent article [Evolutionary Database Design](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html).

LoopBack does not support migration scripts yet, but we are discussing how to implement them for LoopBack 4+, see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/487

Comment: I created a module to handle migration scripts ([loopback4-migration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback4-migration)). Currently this works really well to handle data migrations. The point you mentioned about not using autoupdate/automigrate is correct but then loopback needs to offer a method to generate schema migration scripts based on the model schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the built-in API? 
https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#app-deletemodelbyname

Comment: How and where do I use it? Is it a one-time call, or do I need to keep it with my code?

Comment: Use it as you'd use datasource queries.

Comment: But I already removed the model from the code. Explicitly calling deleteModelByName on a non-existing model makes no code sense. Could you please elaborate on what the new code look like?

Comment: Apologies, apparently this method detaches the model but the data still persists. Check: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/0488cb7ba1b31c207c28eb819755038098e648af/lib/application.js#L176